# Is it safe to cast result of ceil to integer?

Tags: c, floor, ceil

`ceil` function in `C` is declared as `double ceil(double)`. Is it safe to cast return value of the function to `int`? I mean is there any guarantee that the following will never occur (the sample is just to illustrate of what I mean)?

```
double r = ceil(234235.53453);
// imagine r = 234235.9999999 due to round errors or
// due to the peculiarities of the machine arithmetics, etc.
int i = (int)r;
// i = 234235, but must be 234236
```

Of course, I know that the range of `double` is large than the range of `int`, so the cast may fail. My question is not about it, but about rounding errors or machine arithmetics side effects.

Comment: It would be truncated, but there is no danger I can think of. Although I am not an expert in this.

Comment: @iharob: With `long long` probably not, with `int` very well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A 64-bit `double` represents integers of up to 2 in power 53 exactly. Integers larger than that do not have any fractional part when represented as `double`.

In other words, you can safely cast the result of `ceil` or `floor` to an integer, as long as that integer can hold the value.

Comment: There is no need form 'double' to have only 64 bits.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming the result of `ceil` fits in the range of `int` (or whatever the casted type may be), the cast is safe.  Rounding errors only come into play when the number in question can't be expressed exactly in binary.  For example, 0.5 can be expressed exactly as a binary number, but 0.1 cannot.

Since the result of `ceil` is a integer, it can be expressed exactly in binary so there is no rounding error, and is thus safe to cast.

---

You can tell if a number can be expressed as a terminating or non-terminating value by expressing the number as a reduced fraction and looking at the denominator.  If the denominator contains only factors of the base in question, it can be expressed exactly, otherwise it is an infinitely repeating number.

Going back to the example of 0.5 and 0.1, the reduced fractional representation of these numbers is `1/2` and `1/10`.  Both of these numbers can be expressed exactly in decimal because both 2 and 10 contain only factors of 10.  Only the first however can be expressed in binary because 10 has 5 as a factor, which is not a factor of 2.

In the case of integers, they can all be expressed as a fraction with a denominator of 1.  And since 1 is a factor of all integers, any integer can be expressed exactly in any base (including 2).